# IPv6 network in Hyper-V private virtual network

Tags: networking, hyper-v, ipv6

I have created a private virtual network in Windows 2008 R2 hyper-v. Two guests with an adapter each connected to this network is able to ping each other if they use IPv4(used 192.168.10.19 and 192.168.10.20). I'm trying to assign static IPv6 address to the guests and get them to ping each other, but this is not working. This is what I tried:

1. Disabled IPv4 in both guest adapters connected to the private network
2. Assigned IP's fdec:c0bb:c329:0001::7 and fdec:c0bb:c329:0001::8 to the guests
3. Subnet prefix length for both is 64
4. Default gateway and DNS servers are empty

Ping from guest 1 to guest 2 and vice versa fails using IPv6 IP's. How can I get this to work?

Comment: What OSes are the guests running?

Comment: If they're running Windows, what does `netsh int ipv6 show global` and `netsh int ipv6 show int` show? If they're running Linux, what does `ip -6 addr` show?